# Using Jenkins Shared Libraries, import Class from file within vars/?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have two files:

`Constants.groovy`:

```
class Constants
{
    static String foo = "bar";
}
```

`utils.groovy`:

```
import Constants

void func()
{
    assert Constants.foo == "bar"
}
```

From within `utils.groovy`, I would like to import the `Constants` class. Here is the directory structure that the files reside within:

```
.
└── vars
    ├── Constants.groovy
    └── utils.groovy
```

This current setup does not work, and results in the following exception:

> No such property: Constants for class: utils

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to append `.*` to the import:

```
import Constants.*

void func()
{
    assert Constants.foo == "bar"
}
```

I feel a bit silly, but the solution is simple!